# Custom Grid Query Syntax for Rally Portfolio Items for specific Parent Project via WebService API

Tags: javascript, rally

We're starting to experiment with Rally's WebService API for Portfolio Items.  We don't have any issues when creating Custom GRID apps in Rally, but are running into an issue when trying to create Custom HTML apps.  We're trying to query a list of portfolio items (lowest level in portfolio item hierarchy) for a specific parent portfolio item.

We're using the following query, which works for Custom GRID apps, but not for Custom HTML apps:

```
'(Parent.FormattedID = "P123")',
```

We're using the following API version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.32/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.38"></script>
```

Here's the relavant code we're using within the HTML Custom Grid:

```
function onLoad() {
    rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource(
        '123456789',
        '123456790',
        '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
       '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');

   var queryConfig = [];

   queryConfig.push({
       type: 'portfolioitem',
       key  : 'pisQueryKey',
       query: '(Parent.FormattedID = "P123")',
       fetch: 'FormattedID,Name,PortfolioItemType,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate,LeafStoryCount,LeafStoryP>lanEstimateTotal,PercentDoneByStoryCount,PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate'
   });

    rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, drawTable);                    
}
```

We only see "There is nothing to display." under the table headers.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions and/or alternative solutions!

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a bug.  SDK 1.x uses a different web service endpoint (adhoc.js) than the custom grid app and SDK 2.x.  I was able to get it to work correctly by using just the parent's ref in the query instead of its FormattedID:

```
query: '(Parent = /portfolioitem/initiative/12345)'
```

In the meantime I will look into it and see what I can find out.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution and quick response!  Much appreciated.  Works perfectly.